# How use Your Kit custom fontawesome icon in angular project

Tags: javascript, css, angular, font-awesome

I have a fontawesome subscription (paid plan) and I have created a few custom icons. Now, I want to know that how to use them in my angular app. This is my package.json file dependencies.

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
"@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
```

How to use them as below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would bet you will find your use of `@fortawesome` vs `@fontawesome` to be somewhat of a challenge some late night tying to figure something out in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom icons `fontawesome` by different `prefix`

For Solid `fas`  `<i class="fas fa-camera"></i>`

For Regular Pro `far` `<i class="far fa-camera"></i>`

For Light   Pro `fal`   `<i class="fal fa-camera"></i>`

For Duotone Pro `fad`   `<i class="fad fa-camera"></i>`

For  Brands `fab`   `<i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i>`